# How do I hide image on touch with an array of imageviews?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uiimageview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have an array of image views.

```
var imageViewArray = [UIImageView(image: UIImage())]
```

I use a for loop to fill this array with images from urls.  I want to make it so that when I touch one of these images it becomes hidden or alpha: 0.  I tried this:

```
let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(StoryVC.imageTapped))
newImage.userInteractionEnabled = true
newImage.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
```

And I tried adding a tag too but I can't figure out how to get the sender.  I need to be able to run the function to hide the image and know which image to hide, that is the part i'm struggling with.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get `UITapGestureRecognizer` object in your selector's parameter and it has a property `view` that gives you the view which has been tapped.

```
let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.imageTapped(_:)))

func imageTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    guard let tappedImage = sender.view else { return } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The selector should be a function within your class. Here's an example:

```
// Setting up the tapGestureRecognizers
let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(pressed:))
newImage.userInteractionEnabled = true
newImage.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)

// The function that handles the tap event
func pressed(sender: UIImageView!) {
    if sender.alpha == 0{
        sender.alpha = 1
    }
    else{
        self.alpha = 0
    }
}
```

Also make sure to double check my syntax, I don't write with Swift often, so it may have some small errors.